# Query ranks based on number of correct answers

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

I have two tables :

1. `QuizInfo`:

- QuestionID
- FirstAnswerID
- SecondAnswerID
- CorrectAnswerID

2. `PlayerAnswers`:

- QuestionID
- PlayerID
- PlayerAnswerID

`PlayerAnswers` records answer players have given. Player can opt not to answer any given question. I want to give all the players a rank i.e. 1, 2, 3, based on number of correct answers. Is that possible with these two tables only? If so, how?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results

Comment: umm, i do curious, what have you tried? how does the scoring works? do wrong answer net a -1 point? what does `SecondAnswerId` meant?

Comment: Instead of answer it should be FirstOptionID, SecondOptionID.With only these two tables i was unable to do much, however I created another table which increases the counter against PlayerID if player opted for correct answer. I get the count of correct answer against playerid and then use rank function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the correct answers by id, then use the `rank` function

```
with t as (
    select b.playerid, count('dracula') cnt  
    from QuizInfo a
    inner join PlayerAnswers b
        on a.QuestionID = b.QuestionId
        and a.CorrectAnswerID = b.PlayerAnswerID
)    
select playerid
    , rank() over (order by cnt desc) as rnk
from t;
```